# How to create a default Google query string

Tags: search, google-search, search-engines, bing

I'm not very technically-minded, but looking for a way to simplify some work processes.

Is there a way to create a specific Google query string that I can operate by default? As a (very) crude example - say if I wanted to search for restaurants in a particular city where that provided particular cuisines, I might input "Restaurant" "new york" AND cantonese OR chinese OR malaysian....

Rather than copy/paste my search terms each time, is there a way to establish a default search that would allow me to simply enter the city name and then the search engine can add on my additional search terms?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a solution in mind, but it's browser-dependent. Which browser do you use?

Comment: I use Chrome, and Firefox on occasion

Answer (score 1):

The Google Chrome featured called 'Custom Search Engines' can come in handy here.

1. Open Chrome's custom search engines settings page by navigating to the URL `chrome://settings/searchEngines`.
2. Press on the "Add" button above "Other search engines".

Now, we need to define a "custom search engine" that will simplify your workflow. The process here greatly depends on what you're trying to achieve, but I'll give an example for your restaurant scenario.

#### Defining a custom search engine

Broadly speaking, you need to identify the variable in your request as well as the "constants". In the above example, the variable is "New York" and everything else is constant. Here is how we would define a custom search engine for that:

1. In the "Search Engine" field, type a title for your custom search engine. For example, "Restaurant Search".
2. Keyword: a single word which, when written in the address bar, will trigger your shortcut. For example: `restosearch`.
3. URL: somewhat more complicated. For the above example, `{google:baseURL}search?q="Restaurant" "%s" AND cantonese OR Chinese OR malaysian`

Notice that the variable is replaced with `%s` -- this tells Chrome to replace the `%s` with your actual search text.

#### Using your custom search engine

In the Omnibox (Chrome's URL bar), type your keyword (`restosearch`) and press Tab. Then, write your query and press enter.